# django ModelForm DateField initial value not working

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to set initial data in my ModelForm for a datefield but it is not working. Below is my code.

```
def get_date():
    return timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).date()
```

ModelForm:

```
class TransferPacketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    party = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=True, queryset=Party.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }
        )
    )
    transferred_on = forms.DateField(
        required=True, initial=get_date, input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'],
        validators=[validators.get('min_value')(date(2000, 01, 01))],
        widget=forms.DateInput(
            format='%d-%m-%Y',
            attrs={
                'autofocus': 'true', 'class': 'form-control'
            }
        )
    )
    transferred_roi = forms.DecimalField(
        required=True, max_digits=3, decimal_places=2,
        min_value=1.00, max_value=5.00,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }
        )
    )
    transferred_amount = forms.IntegerField(
        required=True, min_value=1, widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Packet
        fields = (
            'transferred_on', 'transferred_amount',
            'transferred_remark', 'transferred_roi',
            'party'
        )

        widgets = {
            'transferred_remark': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }
            )
        }
```

View:

```
class TransferPacketView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Packet
    form_class = TransferPacketForm
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    template_name = 'update_templates/transfer_packet.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'girvi:transferred_packet',
            kwargs={
                'pk': self.get_object()
            }
        )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(TransferPacketView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pkt_obj = self.get_object()
        pkt_obj.is_transferred = True
        pkt_obj.save()
        return redirect(
            self.get_success_url()
        )
```

Form:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_transferred_on">Transferred on:</label></th><td><input autofocus="true" class="form-control" id="id_transferred_on" name="transferred_on" type="text" value="15-02-2015" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_transferred_amount">Transferred amount:</label></th><td><input class="form-control" id="id_transferred_amount" name="transferred_amount" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_transferred_remark">Transferred remark:</label></th><td><textarea class="form-control" cols="40" id="id_transferred_remark" maxlength="150" name="transferred_remark" rows="10">
</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_transferred_roi">Transferred roi:</label></th><td><input class="form-control" id="id_transferred_roi" name="transferred_roi" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_party">Party:</label></th><td><select class="form-control" id="id_party" name="party">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="2">ram pal</option>
<option value="1">shyam pal</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

But html form is rendered without any initial data.

Html form field:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm clearfix">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-6" for="id_transferred_on">Dated</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
        <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date">
            <input id="id_transferred_on" class="form-control" type="text" name="transferred_on" autofocus="true">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong??? Why value is not set to initial data.

Template:

```
<form id="transferPacketForm" class="form form-horizontal width-500 center-block theme-font" role="form" action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    <!-- DIV -->
    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            {% for field in form %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span>{{ field.label }}: {{ field.errors|striptags }}</span><br>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors  %}
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span>Error: {{ error|striptags }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <!-- /DIV -->

    <!-- DIV -->
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm clearfix">
        <label for="id_{{ form.transferred_on.name }}" class="control-label col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-6">Dated</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
            <div class="input-group date" id='datepicker'>
                {{ form.transferred_on }}
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /DIV -->

    <!-- DIV -->
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label for="id_{{ form.party.name }}" class="control-label col-xs-4">{{ form.party.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            {{ form.party }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /DIV -->

    <!-- DIV -->
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label for="id_{{ form.transferred_amount.name }}" class="control-label col-xs-4">Amount</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            {{ form.transferred_amount }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /DIV -->

    <!-- DIV -->
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label for="id_{{ form.transferred_roi.name }}" class="control-label col-xs-4">Interest</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            {{ form.transferred_roi }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /DIV -->

    <!-- DIV -->
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label for="id_{{ form.transferred_remark.name }}" class="control-label col-xs-4">Remark</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            {{ form.transferred_remark }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /DIV -->

    <!-- DIV -->
    <div class="btn-toolbar" align="middle">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-color btn-bg-color" onclick="window.close()">Close</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /DIV -->

</form>
```

Comment: Are you using crispy-forms? Your rendered field has bootstrap layout, hence it is not native django rendering. Maybe the problem is somewhere within rendering process of that 3rd party app?

Comment: No crispy-forms...simple bootstrap implementation.

Comment: Then how do you render your form? Are you using `{{ form.as_p }}` variable, or something along those lines? Because if it simple html in your template, don't expect it to change by itself.

Comment: Tried setting initial value by overriding get_initial method it worked. But why not initial value is setting by form field.

Comment: `{{ form.as_p }}` Not working. Not getting what is wrong.

Comment: Main question is, how do you render the form, because that is where the issue is. Can you post your actual template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70947/discussion-between-user2217267-and-alexey-kuleshevich).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only render initial value if you have no model instance passed to the form. Try this:

```
p = Packet.objects.filter(transferred_on__isnull=True)[0]
# or simply
p = Packet()
f = TransferPacketForm(instance=p)
print(f['transferred_on'])
```

which will not have initial value for that field, but if you do:

```
f = TransferPacketForm()
print(f['transferred_on'])
```

it will. Check it out.

**Edit**

It doesn't apply when you pass `initial` dictionary to the form, it will actually check if the model's field is empty and use the value from the dictionary. So workaround for you is not to use field's `initial`, but forms' `initial` instead, namely through view's `get_initial()` it is.